# Matching files with regular expressions with list.files

Tags: regex, r

I have a pattern for list.files that find some of them, but when I try to specify a little bit more I get nothing.

Here you can see that just adding [:alpha:] which all the files listed before I got one value less which should appear (if I understood well the regular expressions):

```
> list.files(pattern = paste( "UP.csv", sep=""), ignore.case=FALSE)
[1] "TvsPTglult-PglultUP.csv" "TvsPTglusp-PgluspUP.csv"
[3] "TvsPTglysp-PglyspUP.csv" "TvsPTmeth-PmethUP.csv"
> list.files(pattern = paste( "[:alpha:]UP.csv", sep=""), ignore.case=FALSE)
[1] "TvsPTglusp-PgluspUP.csv" "TvsPTglysp-PglyspUP.csv"
[3] "TvsPTmeth-PmethUP.csv"
#Or just without paste and just '
> list.files(pattern = '[:alpha:]UP.csv', ignore.case=FALSE)
[1] "TvsPTglusp-PgluspUP.csv" "TvsPTglysp-PglyspUP.csv"
[3] "TvsPTmeth-PmethUP.csv"  
#And trying to specify with how many times it appears:
> list.files(pattern = '[:alpha:]{6,10}UP.csv', ignore.case=FALSE)
character(0)
#Adding a point to match any single character and I get just one
> list.files(pattern = '[:alpha:].UP.csv', ignore.case=FALSE, full.names=FALSE)
[1] "TvsPTglult-PglultUP.csv"
```

Could someone please explain how I should do to get just all the ones in the first command except Pmeth?
But please **explain**, I would like use more often regular expressions.

Edit:Session Info

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
 [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `[:alpha:]` inside an additional set of square brackets:

```
ff <- c("TvsPTglult-PglultUP.csv","TvsPTglusp-PgluspUP.csv",
        "TvsPTglysp-PglyspUP.csv","TvsPTmeth-PmethUP.csv")

grep("[[:alpha:]]{6,10}UP.csv",ff)  ## 1 2 3
```

Comment: unfortunatly it doesn't work with `list.files(pattern="[[:alpha:]]{6,10}UP.csv")` I get the same  
`[1] "TvsPTglult-PglultUP.csv" "TvsPTglusp-PgluspUP.csv"
[3] "TvsPTglysp-PglyspUP.csv" "TvsPTmeth-PmethUP.csv"`

Comment: Hmm.  `list.files(pattern="-[[:alpha:]]{6}UP.csv")` appears to work (putting the hyphen in explicitly).  Don't know why, though.

Comment: At first glance it does look like a bug -- the same pattern appears to work differently in `grep` and `list.files` -- but I would have to play around with it a bit more to be convinced.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying that you want an `[[:alpha:]]` string of a certain length prior to the string `UP.csv` you might be able to get the job done, but it is a rather implicit solution that is hard for someone else to understand (including yourself in 10 days time).

A more direct and readable way to write it would be to instead state that you don't want files including the word `meth`, by grepping with the argument `invert=TRUE`.

```
grep("meth", list.files(pattern="UP\\.csv$"), invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)
```

`value=TRUE` makes `grep` return the matching values rather than their indices.

Comment: Yes I knew this but I was just trying to get it a more general way to apply when in the folder I have PmethUP.csv and TmethUP.csv

Answer (score 0):

this should do it, check `?regex` for more details

```
list.files(path="./",pattern="[[:alpha:]]*-Pg.*UP\\.csv")
```

Some details: `[[:alpha:]]*` matches 0 or more letters, e.g. any text string. `-Pg` matches that precise string. `.*` matches a string of any printable characters, and finally  `UP\\.csv` matches "UP.csv", you need to escape the "." otherwise it will be interpreted as regex.

Comment: It works thanks. Although I read the `?regex` I still have some problems understanding it, that is why I asked to get an explanation. Rather than a way to make it work.